# Create a list of dictionaries from a list of keys and multiple lists of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My solution

```
keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'ID']

name1 = ['Michael', 'Jordan', '224567']
name2 = ['Kyle', 'Hynes', '294007']
name3 = ['Josef', 'Jones', '391107']

dictList = []
dictList.append(dict(zip(keys, name1)))
dictList.append(dict(zip(keys, name2)))
dictList.append(dict(zip(keys, name3)))
```

Works fine, but is there any other solution, because I will have at least 20000 names, so I am looking how to improve this.

Comment: FWIW, you never return or print anything. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really intending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need a dictionary? Why not just use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Employee = namedtuple('Employee', 'FirstName, LastName, ID')
>>> names_list = [['Michael', 'Jordan', '224567'], ['Kyle', 'Hynes', '294007'], ['Josef', 'Jones', '391107']]
>>> employee_list = map(Employee._make, names_list)
>>> employee_list[0].FirstName
'Michael'
>>> pprint(employee_list)
[Employee(FirstName='Michael', LastName='Jordan', ID='224567'),
 Employee(FirstName='Kyle', LastName='Hynes', ID='294007'),
 Employee(FirstName='Josef', LastName='Jones', ID='391107')]
```

Comment: Thanks.What is _make doing here?

Comment: Its a special class method of `namedtuple`, that generates new instances from a collection or other iterable. Think of it like a generator of named tuples. You can read more at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make), although it just states _"Class method that makes a new instance from an existing sequence or iterable."_

Answer (score 4):

Place all your "name" sublists into the *parent* list `names`. Then you can easily use list comprehension:

```
keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'ID']
names = [
    ['Michael', 'Jordan', '224567'],
    ['Kyle', 'Hynes', '294007'],
    ['Josef', 'Jones', '391107']
]

dictList = [{k:v for k,v in zip(keys, n)} for n in names]
print(dictList)
```

The output:

```
[{'FirstName': 'Michael', 'LastName': 'Jordan', 'ID': '224567'}, {'FirstName': 'Kyle', 'LastName': 'Hynes', 'ID': '294007'}, {'FirstName': 'Josef', 'LastName': 'Jones', 'ID': '391107'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

pandas makes this too easy.

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'ID']
name1 = ['Michael', 'Jordan', '224567']
name2 = ['Kyle', 'Hynes', '294007']
name3 = ['Josef', 'Jones', '391107']

doc_list = [name1,name2,name3]
df = pd.DataFrame(doc_list,columns = keys)
```

So you'll have a DataFrame like this:

```
   FirstName  LastName   ID
0   Michael   Jordan  224567
1      Kyle    Hynes  294007
2     Josef    Jones  391107
```

If your names are already in a file,read_csv would be better.

```
pd.read_csv("file_name.csv",header=keys)//remove the header parameter if it is present in your csv.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append your dictionaries to the list inside a loop, like this:

```
In [1152]: names = [name1, name2, name3]

In [1153]: d = []

In [1154]: for name in names:
      ...:     d.append(dict(zip(keys, name)))
      ...:     

In [1155]: d
Out[1155]: 
[{'FirstName': 'Michael', 'ID': '224567', 'LastName': 'Jordan'},
 {'FirstName': 'Kyle', 'ID': '294007', 'LastName': 'Hynes'},
 {'FirstName': 'Josef', 'ID': '391107', 'LastName': 'Jones'}]
```

---

Or, if you prefer, a list comprehension:

```
In [1160]: d = [dict(zip(keys, name)) for name in names]

In [1161]: d
Out[1161]: 
[{'FirstName': 'Michael', 'ID': '224567', 'LastName': 'Jordan'},
 {'FirstName': 'Kyle', 'ID': '294007', 'LastName': 'Hynes'},
 {'FirstName': 'Josef', 'ID': '391107', 'LastName': 'Jones'}]
```